# Failure to boot / install Linux

Tags: linux, installation, boot

I have a very strange problem. I tried to install Linux on an old computer, but no Live CD would boot except Knoppix.

After several attempts, I got to *nearly* booting Linux Mint Debian edition, and managed to run the Debian (not LMDE, the Debian DVD) installer. However, the Debian installer is extremely slow and as such I decided to run it tomorrow (it's about 5pm).

Here is the [link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=107879) to my post on the Mint forums (to settle out the possible misunderstandings and extra hardware information).

Note that when doing the system profiling on the link I had a Gigabyte GeForce GTX 580. I went back to a GeForce GTX 480 (that's part of what let me boot Debian at all).

Technically I'm getting a new PC in about 2 months, but I want to find out the problem with this one first to avoid having the same problem on the new one. (Going to shop with a Linux CD should freak quite a few people out... I like that but it would be my last resort. Especially considering I'm planning on building it...)

Comment: Have you tried an ubuntu alternate installer cd, or some other non livecd?

Comment: An E6600 isn't that old. But you haven't described what the actual problem you're having is.

Comment: The problem is that I can't boot any liveCD (kernel loads and that's where it ends). I've tried multiple things including a debian DVD installer. Please read the link on the mint forums, lest I copy all that info in here making this about a page long @_@

Comment: If your pc has a built in video card try booting with just that. core2 should be more then enough to boot any of those. WO an error message its tricky to say. I have a barton which is probably 2+ years older then the core2 running fedora 17 and solaris 11.  The realy new video card is the only thing that sticks out, could be that the open nvidia driver on the disks doesnt have an id for it.  Im suprised txt mode didnt work which makes video even more suspect. you could try booting with the no framebuffer txt mode.

Comment: @Kendrick I can boot knoppix, and I tried to install debian with deboostrap. I succeeded the "bare bones install", so no bootloader or drivers yet. However I can't do anything else -> knoppix is 32 bit only (and debian is 64 bit)... So chroot gives a bad exec format to /bin/bash :((

Comment: The distros that work appear to be 486/586, so your pc is probably missing the cmov instruction (or other 686 instructions) ... Try puppy, its 486 compatible and the wary version targets older computers.

Comment: @technosaurus: That's a Core 2 he's using...

Comment: I remember I once had a similar problem - with Knoppix, of all things. In the end it turned out that a specific chip was mis-identified, the kernel tried to load the module for the *identified* chip, and the module (being for the wrong hardware) crashed & burned. I got around that by enabling, at the CD boot prompt, a boot mode that asked me interactively whether to load each module it identified. I noted which step crashed, and skipped the module the next time. You might have to work some magic to do the same for the eventually installed system. Not an answer / solution, but just a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally settled the issue.
Turns out that my BIOS was ~600 version behind (literally). - 3xx to 9xx.

After updating it the only problems remaining was the incompatibility of my nvidia card with nouveau which I settled easily by installing arch and the nvidia drivers without ever touching nouveau.

Lesson in this: Updating BIOS is a good thing.

Comment: ...if successful. Welcome to Mint. ;)

Comment: @DevSolar How is mint relevant at this point? Yes I wanted to install mint initially for a few reasons, but if you look carefully: *I settled easily by installing arch and the nvidia drivers* . [Arch Linux](http://archlinux.org) :). And it was, I'm writing from it.

Comment: I didn't understand "arch" to mean Arch Linux, and was going from your mention of Mint in the question, and your reference to the Mint forums. Well then, welcome to Linux. ;)

Comment: @DevSolar once again I've been on it for quite a while ;) . So I'll just write this to my machine: `echo Welcome to Linux, dear computer!` :)